# Ideal upload speed limit with Azure REST API's through Worker Role

Tags: azure, blob

I would like to know is there ideal upload speed limit while upload to blob through Azure REST API's..Having 2 medium instance of worker role

For 700MB,i am uploading it by spilting into chunks and calling CloudBlockBlob.PutBlock and PutBlockList.How would be ideal time to upload and how to increase the performance.

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance among other things would depend on

- Number of blocks you're uploading concurrently.
- Block size.
- Bandwidth available to you.
- If or not your worker role and the storage account are not in the same data center/affinity group.

Take a look at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee814754.aspx

What it tells you is that for a "Small" sized VM, you get 100Mbps bandwidth. Ideally if uploading blob in blob storage is the only thing your worker role is doing, I would code the application in such a way that I can make maximum use of this bandwidth available to me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ,thanks.Yes my worker role only upload and download files from blob.I have a TCP listener on Port 21 of worker role listening for incoming conn.When user tries to connect it through any FTP client,i'll dispatch incoming client conn on new thread immediately for handling multiple connections. Since I have Blob upload method,which takes the input file and split into chunks & try to upload to blob.My concern is if a single user tries to upload multiple files at a same time,then upload method fails.do i need to handle upload method on new thread for each upload request for a single user.

Comment: Best way to make use of maximum band width available for medium size instance??WOuld like to know the ways to do it.

Comment: [Thinking Out Loud] For a given file, there're 2 variables (Block Size, # of Concurrent Blocks) and one constant factor (Bandwidth). Using this, I think we can come up with a formula to maximize the bandwidth. Since we're transferring data inside Windows Azure, let's assume that our block size is 2 MB. Assuming 100 Mbps (= 12.5 MBps), we can transfer 6 blocks (of 2 MB each) / second or something like this. Obviously these are for ideal scenario but you can play with them and come up with something. HTH.